# Ideal of an affine n-space over an infinite field k.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, roots

Is the ideal of an affine n-space over an infinite field equal to the null set of polynomials? If so, why?

I am not able to fully comprehend the reason why it is so.

Answer (score 0):

This is true almost by definition.

To define the ideal of a given variety, you *start* with the affine $n$-space $\mathbb A^n$.

If your variety is $X$, then the ideal of $X$ is the set of polynomials $f$ such that $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$ whenever $(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in X$.

If $X=\mathbb A^n$, then you want the set of all polynomials that are zero for all input points $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. If the field $k$ is infinite, then this implies that the polynomial itself must be zero.

**Proof hint:** Polynomial interpolation and induction in the number of variables.